# How to iterate a paginatedList faster with PyGitHub?

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

I want to iterate the items of a paginatedList in a fast way but, when I apply a method to the paginatedList, then it takes too much time to execute the program.

Example

'''

```
plist = user.get_starred()

for starred in plist.__iter__():
   print(starred)
```

'''

When i use a method like "**iter**" or others methods for paginatedLists (https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/001970d4a828017f704f6744a5775b4207a6523c/github/PaginatedList.py#L123), the programme becomes very inefficient.

Comment: the question is not clear. what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Finally, my solution was to use Request library instead of PyGitHub, is more efficient for extraction information from GitHub's API.